# I am using drop down list and want to display its value on next page

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using drop down list and want to display its value on next page but it is displaying id instead of it's name if I write code like below and if I take both
in value means value="{{operator.id}}{{operator.operators_name}}" then it is printing output like this 1xyz but I want only xyz to display and 1 for passing another java script function

```
 <select  class="form-control" id="sel1" name="oprator"  data-live-search="true" onchange="getOprInfo(this.value)" >
              <option value="">Select Operator</option>
               {%for operator in operators%}
                <option value="{{operator.id}}">{{operator}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
getOprInfo(value)
{
   setData("value", value);
}

can you used next page

var value = getData("value");
```